# webpack.config: include parameters

Tags: webpack, config

How can I easily include an external configuration file in the `webpack.config.js` file?

We have two or three string constants used in the Webpack config file which may be different for different developers depending on their development environment. I want each developer to have a small file with these properties which is excluded from version control, while the main Webpack config file should obviously be included in version control.

My first try was to have code like this in the user specific config file named `localDevParams.js`:

```
export function developmentApiServer() {
    return 'https://my.server.com/path/';
}
export function otherDevelopmentProperty() {
    return 'blah blah blah';
}
```

and then use

```
import { developmentApiServer } from './localDevParams.js';
```

in the `webpack.config.js` file. But I got the error message `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

Comment: Have you considered .env files? https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv

Comment: The error you are getting is related to you using import as oppose to require. You should use `const developmentApiServer = require('./localDevParams.js').developmentApiServer` to  get around that error.

Comment: @manish Yes, that is a good idea. I used an .env file